# Cannot access WebApi in self-hosted application running on Docker

Tags: c#, docker, swagger

I have a Self-Hosted .NET Framework WebApi application that contains a health check endpoint that I can access locally using Postman. The endpoint I am executing from Postman is `http://localhost:8000/api/health/ping`. Locally the endpoint executes correctly and I get a 200 back. I also have the `SwashBuckle` package installed in my project that I am using to generate a Swagger page for the health check endpoint. If I execute `http://localhost:8000/swagger` locally, I get a 200 back and I am able to see the Swagger page. Everything is working as I would expect locally.

I am seeing issues when I attempt to run my application in a windows container. My DockerFile is as follows

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

COPY ./bin/Debug/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["WebApi.exe"]
```

and my docker run command is as follows `docker run --name WebApiSwagger -d -p 8000:8000 webapiswagger`. I do see the application come up in DockerDesktop but when I attempt to execute `http://localhost:8000/api/health/ping` or `http://localhost:8000/swagger` either in a browser window or Postman I get the error message `HTTP Error 403. The request URL is forbidden.` Here are a few things that I have tried

1. I have tried pinging the container using the container's IPV4 address. For instance `http://172.28.61.217:8000/api/health/ping` but that resulted in the error message `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.`
2. I have given the container a hostname using the command  `docker run --name WebApiSwagger --hostname WebApiSwagger -d -p 8000:8000 webapiswagger` and pinged the container using `http://WebApiSwagger:8000/api/health/ping` but that resulted in the same `HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.` error message.

In the end I would like to access my swagger page from a container but I feel the the forbidden issue has something to do with why I can't seem to access it.

I can access the endpoint from inside of the container. For instance in the container if I do a `http://localhost:8000/api/health/ping` I get a 200 back

This is what my `Startup.cs` looks like

```
internal sealed class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureWebApi(app);
    }

    private void ConfigureWebApi(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        SwaggerConfig.Register(config);

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The title and description is somewhat misleading: [ping (`en.wikipedia.org`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) has a very specific meaning, especially wrt. networking. I'd suggest to [edit] the post and reword it.

Comment: Updated. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Can you show your startup file and see how the swagger is enabled, I.e. do you only enable swagger when the environment is dev? Inside docker, you might have a environment variable prod and your swagger is disabled.

Comment: @CharlesHan I have added my Startup.cs to the question.